# How do I save data in MVC's Session when the load balancer isn't "sticky"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewdata, tempdata

I need to save information in the session and make it available to all web servers in the farm, as the HTTP sessions aren't sticky.

I believe this means that I need to use a [shared-in memory session state provider.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx)

That being said, how do I actually put data into that store from code?

TempData, ViewBag, and all the other variants seem to only work on one page, and I need some variables accessible in multiple pages.

Comment: Configure session state to use [SQL or out-of-proc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx) providers and use `Session` as usual... Not sure where you problem is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different session state providers, including a SQL Server session state provider. You configure it in your `web.config`

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

and then use the `Session` container normally.

To add:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add( key, val );
```

To retrieve:

```
object val = HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]
```

Comment: I forget MVC, and all ASP.NET programming now... how do I use session normally? I keep on googling for the answer and can't find it (getting stuck with answers about Tempdata)